# What airplane is this guy sitting in?

Tags: aircraft-identification

[image: ?]

What airplane is this guy sitting in?

Comment: +1 for “this guy”. 

Comment: wait... is it https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ep2ss.jpg ?

Comment: @uhoh No, wrong side of the Atlantic.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That is an **[Airbus A400M Atlas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbus_A400M_Atlas)**. Here is a picture for reference:

[image: A400M cockpit]
<sup>([Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Airbus_A400M_cockpit_ILA2014.jpg))</sup>

Answer (score 17):

- The airplane is an Airbus A400M  Atlas (credits to Bianfable)
- The airport is Farnborough Airport
- The guy is the (soon to be former) Prime Minister of the UK, Boris Johnson. He opened the [Farnborough air show](https://www.farnboroughairshow.com/)

Comment: *for some values of "soon" :)

Comment: 6th of Sept is the generally accepted date https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2022/jul/20/tory-leadership-race-final-two-what-happens-next-conservative-party-members